# Size of unsigned char is 8 bits but why can I shift it (left or right) by or upto 31 bits?

Tags: c, implicit-conversion, integer-promotion

So here is my code

```
#include <stdio.h>                  
int main(void) {
    unsigned char ch = 244;      
    ch = ch << 31;                   
    return 0;
}
```

I can shift `ch` upto 31 bits that's means `ch` is of 32 bits but how ?
`sizeof(ch)` is also 1 byte only.

Comment: the posted code does not cleanly compile! The compiler outputs this message: *untitled.c:4:10: warning: conversion to ‘unsigned char’ from ‘int’ may alter its value [-Wconversion]*

Comment: I know that :) but I did not receive any warning implicitly that's why I asked here now I got it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> [...] that means `ch` is of 32 bits [...] ?

It isn't.  The result of the shift, which is of type `int`, is truncated to 8 bits when assigned back to `ch`.

You can verify this by examining the value of `ch`.

`gcc` spots this if `-Wconversion` is turned on:

```
$ gcc -Wconversion test.c
test.c:4:13: warning: implicit conversion loses integer precision: 'int' to 'unsigned char' [-Wconversion]
    ch = ch << 31;
       ~ ~~~^~~~~
1 warning generated.
```

Comment: ok but why my compiler is not giving any warning while shifting ? Because we can't shift a value to its max bit which should be 8th bit here. For example I can not do like this on int ( 4 bytes) `4 << 32`

Comment: @Golu: gcc does warn about this if asked.  I've updated the answer.

Comment: @Golu The shift itself is fine: `ch` is implicitly converted to `int`.

Answer (score 3):

1. "[*Integer Promotion*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/integer-promotion+c)" is applied to both operants of the `<<` operator.
2. Then the shifting is done.
3. This is followed by an "[*Implicit Conversion*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/implicit-conversion+c)" of the previous operation's result to the type of the "Left-Hand-Side" value of the assignment operator.